# Error 500: .htaccess RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters

Tags: .htaccess, rest, xampp

I've noticed many questions about that problem, but in my case the htaccess is very simple:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

#somecomment    
RewriteBase /restAPI/   

#continue if condition is true:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # somecomment 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # somecomment 

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] 
#somecomment 
#somecomment 

</IfModule>
```

4-5 weeks about now I haven't problem with that rewritebase, but now I can't start my simple RestAPI :/

Any suggestions why this doesn't work?

Comment: Tried removing "somecomment" and the end of the rewritecond lines?

Comment: Great! Can't believe, but the problem is here -   # somecomment at 8 and 9 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # somecomment 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # somecomment
```

The 500 Error is the result of your line-end comments. Apache does not actually support line-end comments.

> Lines that begin with the hash character "#" are considered comments, and are ignored. Comments may **not** be included on the same line as a configuration directive.

Reference: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html#syntax

Sometimes line-end comments *appear to work* because of a "fluke". If you supply all the arguments to the directive then anything trailing on the line is ignored. But in this case you have not supplied any *flags* (the 3rd argument), so you get the error, it is trying to interpret your `# somecomment` as `RewriteCond` flags.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if your comment on the lines

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  # somecomment 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # somecomment
```

Are not interpreted as comments but as parameters to `RewriteCond`. Remove those (or move them on the line above `RewriteCond`).

IIRC comments are only supported at the beginning of a line in Apache httpd.