# I can't change my streaming website homepage

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to change the homepage of my site but nothing is happening. When entering the code below "DirectoryIndex index.html #to make index.html as index" my home page remains the same. I'm making changes to the file in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^index.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # Change below before deploying to production
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

DirectoryIndex index.html #to make index.html as index
```

My website is written in php and I want to put the homepage in html

Comment: "trying to change the homepage" - By this I assume you are trying to serve `index.html` for requests to the document root (ie. the homepage), instead of routing requests to `index.php`?

Comment: `<ifmodule` is always kind of a bad idea because it just causes your config to silently fail if the module isn't loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
> ```

Change the `*` quantifier to `+`, so that it only matches non-empty URL-paths, to allow the `DirectoryIndex` document (ie. `index.html`) to be served for requests to the homepage, instead of passing the request through to the front-controller (ie. `index.php`). Or, simply use a dot (`.`) as the regex since you aren't doing anything with the captured URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

(The `QSA` flag is not required here.)

Although, since you are using a front-controller pattern (ie. routing all requests to `index.php`), you should probably be configuring the appropriate response to be served from `index.php` instead?

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> DirectoryIndex index.html #to make index.html as index
> ```

You should remove, what you *think* is a comment at the end of the line, ie. "`#to make index.html as index`". That's not actually a comment. Apache does not support line-end comments (only full-line comments are supported). In this instance, `#to`, `make`, `index.html`, `as` and `index` will be seen as additional arguments to the `DirectoryIndex` directive (so you don't actually get an error).

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31770372/369434) to the following question regarding the use of line-end comments:
[Error 500: .htaccess RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770294/error-500-htaccess-rewritecond-bad-flag-delimiters)

---

**UPDATE:**

#### Alternative solution

Try the following instead (this replaces the *entire* `.htaccess` file above):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html)$ - [L]

# Rewrite any request for anything that is not a file to "index.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# Rewrite the homepage only to "index.html"
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [L]
```

The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required. (This is your server so you know if mod_rewrite is enabled or not and these directives are not optional.)

Make sure you've cleared your browser cache before testing.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/VjbLlWSjwvQj

Comment: Okay, so it was. But still no changes to the homepage :(

Comment: @IgorBorges What do you mean by "so it was"? It should be `DirectoryIndex index.html` (not `index.html as index DirectoryIndex` as in your screenshot?)

Comment: No I'm saying I did exactly what you answered but it still didn't work...

Comment: @IgorBorges I've updated my answer with an alternative solution.